# R - Traffic Data

Tags: r

I'm hoping for some help with my data. It is presented as traffic data by year, region_id, road__category_id and all_motor_vehicles. I hope to add all the all_motor_vehicle data for all the road_category_id variables for year region and each year.

For example, for Wales in 1993 I would have the sum of all the motor vehicle data for the road category.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Data:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using `dplyr` from the `tidyverse` package to group the data and do calculations. Assuming your data is called `dat`:

Get the total number of observations for 1993 from Wales for each road cat:

```
require(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  filter(year==1993,
         region_id=='Wales') %>%
  group_by(road_catagory_id) %>%
  summarize(observations=n())
```

Get the total number of cars and taxis for each road cat with the same filters:

```
dat %>%
  filter(year == 1993,
         region_id == 'Wales') %>%
  group_by(road_catagory_id) %>%
  summarize(totCarTaxi = sum(cars_and_taxis)
```

There are many functions you can use to do calculations, look up more information on using `dplyr` [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html).